# Copy Azure SQL Database Schema to create a new one

Tags: sql-server, azure

We have a SalesDatabase in a SQL Server.

There are two database schemas in that database:

- ProductionDataSchema
- DryrunDataSchema

I want to refresh ( Drop and recreate using script) the DryrunDataSchema from ProductionDataSchema.

Is there any SQL command to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-scripts-sql-server-management-studio?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

Connect your Azure SQL Database with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

1. Open the SSMS on your system. **Fill the details to connect your Azure SQL Server** as shown below.

[image]

2. Expand your server by clicking on **+** sign. Similarly expand your database.
3. Now right click on schema for which you want to create the script.
4. Follow: **Script Table as -> DROP And CREATE to -> New Query Editor Window**. This will create your script.

[image]